# How To Customize Angular Date Filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

How To Customize `Angular Date Filter` in `Thai Format` or Another Country format?

**17 March 2017 or 2017-03-17  change to 17 {Thai Month} 2560**

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n

Comment: you can check this link: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date and could you show us how you want to see your date?